# Fourier transform of a random variable

Tags: fourier-analysis, random-variables, integral-transforms

During my research i'm dealing with a stochastic partial differential equation.
The random term appearing in my equation is a tensorial random variable:
$\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x},t)$
Which is a gaussian random variable completely defined by the first two moments:
$<\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x},t)>=\boldsymbol{0}$
$<\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x},t)\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x^{'}},t^{'})>=\frac{2k_{B}T}{\mu}(\delta_{i,j}\delta_{k,l}+\delta_{i,l}\delta_{j,k}) \delta(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}^{'}) \delta(t-t^{'})$

$i,j,k,l$ denote the components of the tensor.

The tensorial random variable is essentially a white noise in space and time.
I'm reading a paper in which the authors take the spatial fourier transform of this random variable.
They report that the fourier transformed second moment is:

$<\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{k},t)\boldsymbol{\sigma}(-\boldsymbol{k},t^{'})>=\frac{2k_{B}T}{\mu}(\delta_{i,j}\delta_{k,l}+\delta_{i,l}\delta_{j,k})\delta(t-t^{'})$

In this formula $\boldsymbol{k}$ is the wave vector.

I don't really understand how this result is obtained, so if anyone could help me with the derivation it would be great, thank sin advance.
I hope the question is clear, if you think it is not, please let me know i'll add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Fourier transform of a delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformDeltaFunction.html) is a constant.
$$FT[\delta(\mathbf y - \mathbf z)] = e^{-2\pi i \mathbf k \cdot \mathbf z}$$
$$\Rightarrow FT[\delta(\mathbf y)] = e^{-2\pi i 0} = 1$$
Now for your variance tensor let $\mathbf x^\prime = \mathbf x + \mathbf y$ which gives you
$$ \langle \sigma(\mathbf x, t)\sigma(\mathbf x + \mathbf y, t^\prime) \rangle = \frac{2k_bT}{\mu}(\delta_{i,j}\delta_{k,l} + \delta_{i,l}\delta_{j,k} )\delta(\mathbf y)\delta(t-t^\prime)$$
Thus Fourier transforming this wrt space ($\mathbf y$) gives back 
$$ \frac{2k_bT}{\mu}(\delta_{i,j}\delta_{k,l} + \delta_{i,l}\delta_{j,k} )\delta(t-t^\prime)$$

As a general comment (unless I've misunderstood something) the notation seems somewhat untidy, either there should be a sum over indexes on the RHS or there should be corresponding indexes $i,j,k,l$ on the LHS, since this doesn't appear to be using Einstein's summation convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; indeed i should have added the summation over indices; but i wrote the question from my smartphone and i already struggled to keep the notation clear. However i also would like to know why the transformed second moment becomes $<\boldsymbol{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{k},t)\boldsymbol{\sigma}(-\boldsymbol{k},t^{'})>$ that is to say, why the second term has $-\boldsymbol{k}$ as argument...

Comment: I'm not too sure of that myself, perhaps you could post a link to the article? The context may be useful.

Comment: Here's the link http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999114001867 the fourier transformation is in the Appendix B

Comment: @user3810266 I can't quite get the derivation to come out nicely but I think it has something to do with the fact the spectral density (i.e. FT of $\sigma$) is a complex value therefore $|\sigma(k)|^2 = \sigma(k)\sigma^*(k)$ where $^*$ is the complex conjugate. The conjugate of the Fourier transform of a real function differs only by having $e^{2\pi i kx}$ and not $e^{-2\pi ikx}$.